# javascript parameter passing not Working Showing Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, three.js

I have a javascript code in js file which have following function

```
var obj, mtl;

init();
animate();
var MYLIBRARY = MYLIBRARY || (function () {
    var _args = {}; // private
return {
    init: function (Args) {
        _args = Args;
        // some other initialising
    },
    getValue: function () {
        obj = _args[0];
        mtl = _args[1];
    }
};
} ());
```

and now I want to pass some value to `MYLIBRARY`  that way I can use it;
But when I pass the Value as

```
<script src="App_Themes/Assets/js/loaders/JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             MYLIBRARY.init(["obj/Dress/anarkali.obj", "obj/Dress/anarkali.mtl"]);
             MYLIBRARY.getValue();
        </script>
```

It gives me this Error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined

Comment: There's no `substr()` in the posted code, you've omitted the part that causes the error ?

Comment: where should I post the code substr()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the Question was wrong
`MYLIBRARY` is Defined in `Jscript.js` and args where initialize after

So, I put the `MYLIBRARY` Out of `Jscript.js`

```
<script>
var MYLIBRARY = MYLIBRARY || (function () {
var _args = {}; // private
return {
    init: function (Args) {
        _args = Args;
        // some other initialising
    },
    getValue: function () {
        obj = _args[0];
        mtl = _args[1];
    }
};
} ());

</script>
```

and after that this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         MYLIBRARY.init(["obj/Dress/anarkali.obj", "obj/Dress/anarkali.mtl"]);
         MYLIBRARY.getValue();
    </script>
<script src="App_Themes/Assets/js/loaders/JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```